# How to paint a larger TrackBar thumb which can move when the mouse drags it?

Tags: winapi, canvas, c++builder, trackbar

I want to create my own TrackBar, and I want to paint a bigger thumb. Here is my code.

```cpp
void __fastcall TTrackBar1::CrnNotify(TWMNotify &Message)
{
    LPNMCUSTOMDRAW lpDraw = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)Message.NMHdr;

    if(lpDraw->hdr.code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
    {
        try
        {
            m_pCanvas->Lock();
            m_pCanvas->Handle = lpDraw->hdc;
            if(!(lpDraw->dwDrawStage & CDDS_ITEM))
                Message.Result = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
            else
                CrnCustomDraw(Message);
        }
        __finally
        {
            m_pCanvas->Handle = NULL;
            m_pCanvas->Unlock();
        }
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TTrackBar1::CrnCustomDraw(TWMNotify &Message)
{
    LPNMCUSTOMDRAW lpDraw = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)Message.NMHdr;

    if(!(lpDraw->dwDrawStage & CDDS_PREPAINT))
        return;

    TRect rct = lpDraw->rc;

    if(lpDraw->dwItemSpec == TBCD_THUMB)
    {
        TRect drct;

        if(Orientation == trVertical){
            drct.left = rct.left - 5;
            drct.right = rct.right + 5;
            drct.top = rct.top - 10;
            drct.bottom = rct.bottom + 10;
        }
        m_pCanvas->RoundRect(drct,2,2);
        ::Graphics::TBitmap *bmp= new ::Graphics::TBitmap;
        bmp->Transparent = true;
        bmp->LoadFromFile("UI//slider.bmp");
        m_pCanvas->CopyRect(drct, bmp->Canvas, TRect(0,0,bmp->Width,bmp->Height));
        delete bmp;
    }
```

I create a new `TRect` to copy my bmp to the thumb, but the problem is  my thumb will not follow the Rect except the original area of thumb. Just like this.

[image: only the original area of thumb will move with mousedrag]

As long as you select another form, it will repaint the image on the right position.

I want to know, how can I paint a TrackBar thumb which can move with the mouse correctly when dragged?

Comment: You are simply drawing a larger thumb bitmap onto the `HDC`, but you are not telling the OS that the extra pixels actually belong to the real thumb. You will likely have to handle the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message directly so you can manually reposition the real thumb when dragging the mouse over these extra pixels. You might also try having your TrackBar class handle the `TBM_GETTHUMBRECT` and/or `TBM_GETTHUMBLENGTH` message(s) to adjust the values that the TrackBar returns by default. Or at least send a `TBM_SETTHUMBLENGTH` message to itself (make sure the `TBS_FIXEDLENGTH` style is not enabled).

Comment: On a side note, you should not be loading your bmp image on every draw event. Preload it ahead of time, such as in your class constructor, and then just reuse it for each draw. Later on, you should consider embedding it into your EXE's resources instead of using an external file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau well，then how to handle the messages in my class?

Comment: Moves the slider and sends the `TB_THUMBTRACK` notification code when tracking the mouse. A trackbar notifies its parent window of user actions by sending the parent a WM_HSCROLL or WM_VSCROLL message. I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Trackbar Notification Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/trackbar-controls#trackbar-notification-messages)